# How do I determine if onError was called in a GRPC ServerInterceptor?

Tags: java, grpc

I want to wrap my service calls in an implicit transaction rather than having to explicitly use `TransactionTemplate` to wrap the existing call.

I put a bunch of log statements in my ServerInterceptor class but it does not appear any of them can detect that `onError` was called in the service.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class TransactionProviderGrpcInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
  private final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

  @Override
  public <R, Q> ServerCall.Listener<R> interceptCall(
      final ServerCall<R, Q> call, final Metadata headers, final ServerCallHandler<R, Q> next) {

    return new ForwardingServerCallListener.SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<>(
        next.startCall(call, headers)) {
      private TransactionStatus tx;

      /** Mark the transaction as rollback only when cancelled. */
      @Override
      public void onCancel() {

        log.error(
            "onCancel setRollbackOnly tx={}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        tx.setRollbackOnly();
        log.error(
            "onCancel before super tx={}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        super.onHalfClose();
        log.error(
            "onCancel after super tx = {}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
      }

      @Override
      public void onMessage(final R message) {

        log.error(
            "onMessage before super tx = {}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        super.onMessage(message);
        log.error(
            "onMessage after super tx = {}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
      }

      @Override
      public void onComplete() {

        log.error(
            "onComplete before super tx = {}, tx={}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(),
            tx);
        super.onComplete();
        log.error(
            "onComplete after super tx = {}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
      }

      /**
       * Obtained all the messages from client, about to close so at this point commit the
       * transaction. It needs to be done here as the transaction is no longer available {@link
       * #onComplete()}.
       */
      @Override
      public void onHalfClose() {

        log.error(
            "onHalfClose before super tx = {}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
          super.onHalfClose();
        log.error(
            "onHalfClose after super tx = {} headers={}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(),
            headers);
        if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
          transactionManager.commit(tx);
          log.error(
              "onHalfClose after commit tx = {}",
              TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onReady() {

        log.error(
            "onReady before getTransaction tx = {}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        tx =
            transactionManager.getTransaction(
                new DefaultTransactionDefinition(PROPAGATION_REQUIRED));
        log.error(
            "onReady after getTransaction tx = {}",
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
      }
    };
  }
}
```

`onHalfClose()` does not throw any exception at all when `onError` is closed and that's about the only place I have where the transaction is still active.

```
onReady before getTransaction tx = false
onReady after getTransaction tx = true
onMessage before super tx = true
onMessage after super tx = true
onHalfClose after super tx = true headers=Metadata(content-type=application/grpc,user-agent=grpcurl/v1.8.7 grpc-go/1.48.0)
onHalfClose after commit tx = false
onComplete before super tx = false, tx=org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus@68f8b4ba
onComplete after super tx = false
rpc.server.RequestLoggingGrpcInterceptor [64e90719856c7e2e906849013c6b53e2,906849013c6b53e2,] INFO com.devhaus.rpc.Greeter/SayHello 7ms cancelled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

> onHalfClose() does not throw any exception at all when onError is closed

`onHalfClose` is called when the client "half-closes" the call by closing the client stream and is not related to any `onError` processing.

Assuming you are talking about `onError` being called on the server side i.e. the service is closing the call with an error then in the interceptor you can detect it by creating a wrapper call since you want to intercept events from the server to the client. An example is [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/gcp-observability/src/main/java/io/grpc/gcp/observability/interceptors/InternalLoggingServerInterceptor.java#L134) where `SimpleForwardingServerCall` is extended to intercept `close(Status status, Metadata trailers)` being called by the service. Hope that answers your question.